# 2 forms.Form 1 is a log in screen, form 2 has a stopwatch.How to switch between them but the stopwatch wont stop?

Tags: c#, winforms

form 1 has a button which gets you to form 2.(When pressed form 1 closes form 2 shows)

form 2 has a stopwatch which automatically starts once you ve pressed the button in form1

form 2 also has a button which gets you back to form 1.(when pressed form 2 closes form 1 shows)

The problem is that when switching btween form 1 to form 2 for the SECOND time a new form 2 window is created and that means that the stopwatch restarts.

I want to be able to switch between the forms and the stopwatch will work non - stop since the very first log - in and stops only when i terminate the app

I have ideas on how to fix that but im completely new in C# so i dont know how to make that happen.Try to be specific with your answers and give me some coded examples of your thoughts if that s possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you *Close()* form2, that the stuff in it gets destroyed. So you either need a seperate *Thread* for your *StopWatch* or you could try to set the form to invisible while it is not shown.

Comment: Try another Thread then, might well be that if the Form isn't visible, the UI-Thread won't update your stopwatch.

Comment: i thought of that so here s what i used:

1.visible property

2.minimize to normal / norma to minimize code

The problem is that not only the old window gets back but a new one is also created.

what do you mean by saying seperate thread for the stopwatch?