# stopwatch problems

Tags: c#

i have a stop watch which starts once the application starts(stopwatch 1)

i need to make another one which counts a total time(stopwatch 2)

For example:

Application starts for the first time on 17/9 at 12:50

stopwatch 1 starts counting on 17/9 at 12:50

stopwatch 2 starts too.Same date and time.

Application works for 2 hrs

Application terminates (stopwatch 1 is set to 00:00:00 , stopwatch 2 is set to 02:00:00)

Application starts on 18/9 at 13:00

stopwatch 1 starts counting on 18/9 at 13:00 (from 00:00:00)

stopwatch 2 starts counting too.Same date and time (NOT from 00:00:00 but 02:00:00)

Application works for another 2 hrs

Apllication terminates (stopwatch 1 is set to 00:00:00, stopwatch 2 is set to 04:00:00)

how can i do that?

In C i could code it so the program would make a text file and write/retrieve information.Can i do that here?

If i cant, is there some other way to save info in some file and retrieve it whenever i want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 forms.Form 1 is a log in screen, form 2 has a stopwatch.How to switch between them but the stopwatch wont stop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453554/2-forms-form-1-is-a-log-in-screen-form-2-has-a-stopwatch-how-to-switch-between-t)

Comment: yes exactly ..asked by same user

Comment: that s the other problem i have and i dont know how to solve!:\

Comment: You already provided the algorithm, why you have troubles implementing it?

Comment: i dont know HOW to do it.That s my problem.
i know how to code only in C and some fake language they taught us at high school.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the same object persist between different processes, no - but you can easily write out the total time so far. How you choose to do that is up to you - but basically it's just a number. Store it in the registry, put it in a file, whatever you want.

Then you'd just just create *one* `Stopwatch` in each process, load the previous total (e.g. as a `TimeSpan` or maybe the number of elapsed milliseconds) and add the time elapsed by the new stopwatch before you write out the new tota.

Comment: I ve understood the logic of your answer and by that i can say that your answer is great!
But im new in C#.I ve just started learning, i have ideas about how to solve it but i dont know to how to do it.Could you tell me which parts of C# i have to study so i can get started?

Comment: @csd: Well, IO would be a good start - saving data to files. Possibly XML if you want to save it in XML format...